# Linux Lamp Without PHP5-MySQLi/PDO?

Tags: php, linux

I have just recently installed a LAMP Server with this php installation parameters:

`php5-sybase`, `php5-mysql`, `php`, `php-libabachemod` and a few more. I do not have the MySQLI or PDO Classes inside my installation? How Can I do This? I have checked in php.net on the instalation, nd it makes no sense to me. I was wondering if someone could clarify?

I have tried
`sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli php5-pdo` But this does not work

Running:

```
    if (function_exists('PDO')) {
    echo "functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "functions are not available.<br />\n";
}
```

Returns functions are not avilable

and the same if I run `if (function_exists('mysqli'))`

Comment: "does not work" is not an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: Most (if not all) Linux distros have all the LAMP components readily available through their repositories and if some of the components (lets say Apache modules) aren't available in core repositories there are 3rd party repos which do have them. Which distro are you using?

Comment: You need to install meta packages instead of every component separatelly. Try `sudo apt-get install php5 mysql-server apache2`.

Comment: I have all the following packages installed: **`apache2, php5, php5-sybase, php5-libapachemod, php5-mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-server, mysql-client`**

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you don't have PDO loaded? Is it listed when you use `apache2ctl –M`? BTW, PDO is not a "function". Its a class so you should actually use `class_exists()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your installation without `PDO` using PECL wont work as PDO is now in the core package of **`php5-sqlite`**

and `MySQLi` is a core package of **`php5-mysqlnd`** and **`php5-mysql`**

If you already have tried the

```
pecl install PDO

pecl install PDO_MYSQL
```

then you will recieve an error and will need to purge your installation packages inorder to run with PDO/MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` add the following lines:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Then restart:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d apache2 restart
```

Comment: Functions are not enabled, even after adding the lines in my loaded php configuration? Have I installed the correct packages?